# How to add Java bin folder path in Windows path system

Tags: java

i have a problem with running a Java software which is made for Windows.
Actually I want run it on kali Linux but whenever I try to run the soft
it tells me add Java bin folder path in Windows path system variable.

and thats my Java version

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9):

**Add Variables - Java**

**First, you need to Locating the Environment Variables**

**1.** Open up the system properties **(WinKey + Pause)** and you should see the below screen.

[image]

**2.** From the system properties, tab select the **"Advanced"** link. This should take you to the below screen.

[image]

**3.** From the System Properties screen select the **"Advanced Tab"**. On this screen click the  **"Environment Variables"** button.

**4.** You should now be seeing something like the below screen.

[image]

**Now You Are Ready To Add Variables - JAVA**

In the **system variables** section click in the **"New"** button.

In here enter the variable name : **JAVA_HOME**

Enter the variable value as the location of the java jdk installed in the previous section. (This is assuming you already have installed Java SDK. If you haven't now is the time to do it)

For Example of my location below. **(Please note the variable value will vary depending on your install location and version of the jdk)**

[image]

Click ok to complete this action. Once completed you should see the **JAVA_HOME** variable in the list of system variables.

Next, you need to add the newly created **JAVA_HOME** variable on to your path.

To do this locate the **"Path"** variable in the system variables list. Select it and click the edit button.

This should bring up the below option.

[image]

Scroll to the end of the **"variable value"** field and append on the following

**;%JAVA_HOME%\bin**

Click **"OK"** to confirm and leave the edit path screen.

Once complete click **"OK"** to confirm and leave the Environment variables screen.

Next, open a ***new*** command prompt **(Winkey + R then type cmd)** and run **"java -version"** to verify that it is correctly installed.

If it is you should see something similar to the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**WINDOWS SOLUTION:** To make sure that Windows can find the Java compiler and interpreter:

Select Start -> Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH. ...
Prepend C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin; to the beginning of the PATH variable.

**OTHER OS SOLUTIONS:** https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 0):

**I received the following error when installing software:** `check that java is set in the system path` Then I realized that this program is written in Java and I do not have it in the system.
Then I installed JAVA and saw that the program runs well

download java: https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
and add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `Environment Variables>path`