# Cordova cannot detect java version

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I get this error message since this morning

> Android Studio project detected
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin (node:3276)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check
>   failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\walknsmile\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:370:19
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\User\Documents\walknsmile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\User\Documents\walknsmile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\User\Documents\walknsmile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\walknsmile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
>       at runSingle (C:\Users\User\Documents\walknsmile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
>       at flush (C:\Users\User\Documents\walknsmile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) (node:3276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:3276) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

What did i tried:

- 32 bit java(yes i updated the env. variable to the P. Files(X86))
- reinstalled android studio and android sdk several times
- deleted any other java sdk
- reinstalled both 64 and 32 bit java sdk several times
- rebooted the laptop
- reinstalled both ionic3 and cordova

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to set `JAVA_HOME` without the "\bin" (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\`)

To do it: 
`Start -> Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> New`

- In variable name : insert `JAVA_HOME`
- In variable value : insert `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40`

This link explains better how to do it: 
[How to add Java bin folder path in Windows path system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699600/how-to-add-java-bin-folder-path-in-windows-path-system)

Comment: yes, and it was also bad,  but we found the solution: i used the java home in the sys var "path", not in the env var "path"